# Finding sources for Kent Family Genealogy?

Tags: sources, new-england, source-reliability

In my family history research, I found this book about Kent family genealogy:

[“History and Genealogy Of The Kent Family. Descendants of Richard Kent, Sen. who came to America in 1633”](https://archive.org/stream/historygenealogy00dale#page/n3/mode/2up)
By E.J. Dale and Edward E. Kent

The first couple pages describe Richard Kent’s origins in England / New England, and then after that it give the names of his descendants to the 8th generation (in over 150 pages).

There is an index but no mention of any source.

Is there any place to look for the source of this information, or do I just need to start searching the historical records until I find the information I’m trying to verify?

Comment: Similar to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9224/1006 but I would not say it was a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a book's author does not cite sources for its information then I think that you will need to start searching the historical records until you find the information that you are trying to verify.

I recommend starting with pieces of information that are close to the present time to double-check that the ancestors you find are actually those that the book asserts them to be.

Starting with the earliest purported ancestors may lead to much effort being wasted learning about people who you later find are not your ancestors.

Answer (score 2):

You don't list the publication date, but if either of the authors is still living, you could track them down and inquire about their sources.

I realize this is probably not an option, as the older a published genealogy is, the less likely it is to be sourced, and also less likely to have living authors.

Comment: Page 6/176 of the images in the question link suggests 1899 might be when it was published (or reached the library).