# Most current information on parents of Lydia Redfield Bayley?

Tags: united-states, connecticut

Can someone please provide a source(s) for the most current information on the parents of Lydia Redfield Bayley/Bailey?

History of New London, Connecticut: from the first survey of ... Caulkins, Frances Manwaring, 1795-1869, Pgs. 279 & 280 - States  her father is James Redfield, son of William & Rebecca Redfield of New London, CT.  However, that info. is disputed in Genealogical history of the Redfield family in the United States ... Redfield, John Howard, 1815-1895, Pg. 7, which names William & Rebecca as her parents, instead of grandparents.

Has this info. been accepted as proof?

What's the latest thinking on this?

I wish this genealogy site (and others) would simply list the most recent info. for these older ancestors.  Simply a name, dates: b/m/d/bur, and parents & spouse(s), would be really great.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  What timeline do you have for Lydia's life after her birth?  It may shed some light as to who her parents are more likely to have been.

Comment: Any answer I made to this question would be a near-duplicate to my answer here: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/9227/1006

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you have to look at a bigger picture to determine which *fact* you believe. From your first source, [Genealogical and Biographical Record of New London County, Connecticut ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=wPsnAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA589&dq=genealogy%20lydia%20redfield%20bailey%20new%20london%20ct&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi22f2ajPXlAhXaJzQIHf3ND20Q6AEwAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=genealogy%20lydia%20redfield%20bailey%20new%20london%20ct&f=false)

> Thomas Bailey son of William and Mary moved from Virginia to New
>   London Conn in 1651 On Jan Io **1655** he married Lydia daughter of
>   James Redfield.

from the second source , [Genealogical history of the Redfield family in the United States](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q3hMAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=genealogy%20lydia%20redfield%20bailey%20new%20london%20ct&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix3qbsivXlAhVJqp4KHZ_EDoI4ChDoATAEegQIAxAC#v=onepage&q&f=false)
edited by William Charles Redfield we get the following concerning the father of James Redfield:

> ...His death took place about April or May 1662 and was probably not
>   unexpected for in March of that year he had conveyed his house to
>   Thomas Roach who had married his daughter Rebecca and on the 1st of
>   April ***he had provided for his son by apprenticing him in the trade of
>   tanner***

He would not have apprenticed out an adult son who had been married in 1654, so I would favor the Redfield version of the lineage, since it provides a prospective age for James which does not match the marriage date both volumes agree on.

To further support this you might attempt to find probate information if a will was executed after the death of William Redfield...